# django rest framework assertionError

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

AssertionError: When a serializer is passed a `data` keyword argument you must call `.is_valid()` before attempting to access the serialized `.data` representation.
You should either call `.is_valid()` first, or access `.initial_data` instead.

views.py:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from drfw.serializers import NameSerializers
class restapiView(APIView):
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        alphabets=['A','B','C','D','E']
        return Response({'msg':'latters','alphabets':alphabets})
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        serializer=NameSerializers(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid:
            name=serializer.data.get('name')
            msg='Hello{}'.format(name)
            return Response({'msg':msg})
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors,status=400)
```

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
class NameSerializers(serializers.Serializer):
    name=serializers.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`is_valid` is a method. So you need to call it.

Replace `if serializer.is_valid:` with `if serializer.is_valid():`